# Hazelcast with Spring-Boot -- Failed to serialize 'org.springframework.session.MapSession'

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast, spring-session

I am attempting to get session replication working via Hazelcast in a JSF app in Spring-Boot using Spring-Session.

I have the following dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.session', name: 'spring-session-core', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.session', name: 'spring-session-hazelcast', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'com.hazelcast', name: 'hazelcast', version: '3.11'
```

My Spring-Boot app class has the @EnableHazelcastHttpSession annotation, with the following bean defined:

```
@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    MapAttributeConfig attributeConfig = new MapAttributeConfig()
            .setName(HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE)
            .setExtractor(PrincipalNameExtractor.class.getName());

    Config config = new Config();

    config.getMapConfig(HazelcastSessionRepository.DEFAULT_SESSION_MAP_NAME)
            .addMapAttributeConfig(attributeConfig)
            .addMapIndexConfig(new MapIndexConfig(
                    HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, false));

    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
}
```

This appears to be working and HazelCast starts up with a default config when the app starts. However, I get a serialization error when I log in to the app. The ultimate cause of the serialzation error is that AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext is not serializable. It seems like I'm 99% of the way there, any idea what I've missed?

```
2018-11-29 11:24:23,475 - ERROR - [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.cached.thread-2] - [,,] - c.h.map.impl.operation.EntryOperation    : [172.28.208.1]:5701 [dev] [3.11] Unexpected error on Offloadable execution
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'org.springframework.session.MapSession'
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:75)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:157)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:133)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:118)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperation$EntryOperationOffload$2.run(EntryOperation.java:347)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1790)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor142.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1128)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.write(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:114)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.write(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:107)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:154)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
2018-11-29 11:24:23,476 - ERROR - [http-nio-8080-exec-4] - [,,] - o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'org.springframework.session.MapSession'
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:75)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:157)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:133)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:118)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperation$EntryOperationOffload$2.run(EntryOperation.java:347)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:127)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(InvocationFuture.java:79)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:162)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.executeOnKeyInternal(MapProxySupport.java:1099)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.executeOnKeyInternal(MapProxyImpl.java:109)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.executeOnKey(MapProxyImpl.java:757)
    at org.springframework.session.hazelcast.HazelcastSessionRepository.save(HazelcastSessionRepository.java:246)
    at org.springframework.session.hazelcast.HazelcastSessionRepository.save(HazelcastSessionRepository.java:108)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:240)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:685)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1790)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor142.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1128)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.write(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:114)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.write(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:107)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:154)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:133)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:118)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperation$EntryOperationOffload$2.run(EntryOperation.java:347)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
2018-11-29 11:24:23,477 - ERROR - [http-nio-8080-exec-4] - [,,] - o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'org.springframework.session.MapSession'
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:75)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:157)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:133)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:118)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperation$EntryOperationOffload$2.run(EntryOperation.java:347)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:127)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(InvocationFuture.java:79)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:162)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.executeOnKeyInternal(MapProxySupport.java:1099)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.executeOnKeyInternal(MapProxyImpl.java:109)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.executeOnKey(MapProxyImpl.java:757)
    at org.springframework.session.hazelcast.HazelcastSessionRepository.save(HazelcastSessionRepository.java:246)
    at org.springframework.session.hazelcast.HazelcastSessionRepository.save(HazelcastSessionRepository.java:108)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:240)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:685)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1790)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor142.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1128)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.write(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:114)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.write(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:107)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:154)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:133)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:118)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperation$EntryOperationOffload$2.run(EntryOperation.java:347)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JCN, do you have only 1 Hazelcast member (embedded) or is there any other members. I have a similar app, just updated the versions and seems working fine. spring-hazelcast-session uses EntryProcessor to add/update session attributes so all members in the cluster need to have `org.springframework.session.MapSession` class & all its dependencies.

Comment: Only one member. I am just trying to get the simplest case working, then refine the hazelcast config over time. What versions of Spring-Boot and Spring-Session, etc are you using?

Comment: I updated spring-session to 2.1.2, Hazelcast to 3.11 & spring-boot to 2.1.0 & it worked fine.